# Python Regex. Capturing text between matches issue

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Quite new to regex and having trouble getting the right match.

I have the following string:

> The AGM will be held at the Company's registered office at Unity House, Telford Road, Basingstoke, Hampshire, RG21 6YJ on 13 January 2016 at 10.00 a.m.
>
> The Company announces that its 2016 Annual General Meeting will be held on 11 February 2016 at 10.00 a.m. at Hangar 89, London Luton Airport, Luton, Bedfordshire, LU2 9PF.

I am trying to extract the address from the last occurrence of 'at' till the postcode. So Unity House, Telford Road, Basingstoke, Hampshire, RG21 6YJ and Hangar 89, London Luton Airport, Luton, Bedfordshire, LU2 9PF

This is what I use `(at)(?!.*at)(.*)\s([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})`
it extracts only the second address. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: You asked to match the rest of a line if it does not contain `at`, and there is `at 10.00 a.m.` on the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to use `((?:(?!at).)*)` instead `(?!.*at)(.*)` for avoiding to skip over `at`

```
(at)((?:(?!at).)*)\s([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vK5aY4/3)

If you use `(at)(?!.*at)(.*)` with s flag, there is only at the last `at` not another `at` ahead. So it is expected that only the last one would match. `(at)((?:(?!at).)*)` will not skip over another `at`.